# Trying to run and plot dynamic time warping of two arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, curve, dtw

I am trying to understand how to implement dynamic time warping (DTW) to compare time series curves in python. I am trying to take the curves of two arrays, and measure the distance between them, and then plot the two curves with lines connecting each node, as you would see in characteristic DTW plots.

I am trying the following experimental code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

from fastdtw import fastdtw

s = np.array([205, 10, 203, 27, 505, 60, 704, 80, 900, 24, 400, 260])
z = np.array([230, 25, 236, 22, 520, 55, 653, 70, 967, 15, 480, 190])
distance, path = fastdtw(s, z, dist=euclidean)
print(distance)
```

I am following an example from `fastdtw` documentation: https://pypi.org/project/fastdtw/

I have two arrays: "s" and "z", which I am treating as time series data, but just without the timestamps, and at equal time intervals. This code takes my two arrays, "s" and "z", and computes the distance between them, which reveals to be: 385.0

So then I can find the distance between these two curves, but I am not sure how to actually plot this distance, such as with a plot like this (I believe this is called a "two way" DTW plot): https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/py-images/Figure_2.png

This is using the `fastdtw` package, but I also want to use the dtw-python, since this also seems like a good option. I am trying to work from this `dtw-python` documentation example: https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/python/

I am trying this experimental code:

```
from dtw import *
alignment = dtw(s, z, keep_internals=True)
print(alignment)
```

and this prints:

```
DTW alignment object of size (query x reference): 12 x 12
```

This isn't really telling me much though, since I want to reveal the DTW distance between the curves.

I also try plotting this DTW run with:

```
alignment.plot(type="twoway")
```

But I get this error: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Which is confusing me, because I do not have any NaN values in my arrays, I think.

Given my two arrays, which are essentially serving as y-axis values to be plotted as curves, how can I find the DTW distance between them and plot them as a DTW distance matching plot?

The idea is to keep swapping in new arrays in my dataset and keep comparing the distances to see which arrays have the most similar curve shapes. I want to match curves with the most similar shapes, and to my understanding, this means the lowest DTW distance.

Comment: Using `python-dtw` version 1.1.14, I was able to get output for both twoway and threeway plots.  It worked whether I z-normalized each array or not.